# ifstream.read fails on an existing file if a previous open fails

Tags: c++, ifstream

In my code an ifstream object tries to open a non existing file, which fails, then opens an existing file which succeeds.
However the subsequent read fails.

If the existing file is opened without a previous fail then the read succeeds.

What clean up am I missing after the open fails?

The following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *buf = new char[10];

    std::ifstream ifstr;

    ifstr.open("ExistingFile.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    std::cout << ifstr.is_open() << std::endl;
    ifstr.read(buf, 4);
    std::cout << ifstr.fail() << std::endl;
    ifstr.close();

    ifstr.open("NonExistingFile.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    std::cout << ifstr.is_open() << std::endl;
    ifstr.read(buf, 4);
    std::cout << ifstr.fail() << std::endl;
    ifstr.close();

    ifstr.open("ExistingFile.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    std::cout << ifstr.is_open() << std::endl;
    ifstr.read(buf, 4);
    std::cout << ifstr.fail() << std::endl;
    ifstr.close();

    return 0;
}
```

produces

```
1
0
0
1
1
1
```

Comment: You should clear `ifstr.clear()` previous errors

Comment: I had tried that, but before the close. Calling it after the close does the trick, thanks!

Comment: @RaulAndres Please, post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clear ( ifstr.clear() ) previous errors

If you clear the stream before closing if, ifstr.close() will likely set the ifstr fail flag. Don't close the stream if is_open() fails

Comment: Yes, the close after the clear was reintroducing the error state

Answer (score 3):

You may need to add `ifstr.clear();` after `ifstr.close();` to clear the fail bits.